# Speed up a select query on a table with date parts in separate columns

Tags: sql

The following query is taking a very long time to run.

The logins table has 10M records, and there's an index on month, day and year. What could be done to speed up the query?

```
SELECT
cast(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date) as loginDt, logins.person
FROM logins
LEFT JOIN MIN_LUNCH
    ON MIN_LUNCH.person = logins.person
    AND MIN_LUNCH.date = cast(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date)
WHERE
    cast(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date) between '01/01/2010' and '03/01/2010'
```

Comment: what do the tables look like?

Comment: Fix your database structure, use a real date datatype in table `logins`

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using

Answer (score 0):

To fix your query, you would have to fix you table structure. 
Consider either using a `BIGINT` column to store a unix-timestamp or a `DATE` column. This would make querying the database significantly easier, as well as faster.

What you query may look like after changing the structure:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(logins.login_date, '%m-%d') as loginDt, 
  logins.person
FROM 
  logins
  LEFT JOIN MIN_LUNCH ON MIN_LUNCH.person = logins.person AND MIN_LUNCH.date = logins.date
WHERE 
  logins.date between 1262332800 and 1267430400;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to simplify the `WHERE` clause, for the interval of date that you provided:

```
WHERE logins.month IN (1, 2, 3) AND logins.year = 2010
```

This part of the query should be able to use existing indexes, but you are still left with the `JOIN` condition, where you need to match a `date` datatype with three columns containing date parts:

```
MIN_LUNCH.date = cast(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date)
```

Here, for every record, your RDBMS needs to perform a casting operation; this defeats existing indexes.

---

For this reason and for the (great) cause of SQL datatypes, I do recommend that you fix your database structure and store dates as `date`s in the `logins` table.

You could simply add a new column and fill it from the existing data:

```
ALTER TABLE logins ADD login_date DATE; -- or the relevant date datatype for your RDBMS
UPDATE logins SET login_date =
    CAST(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date);
```

From there on, you can use simple joins between both tables. Queries should benefit from following indexes:

```
logins(person, login_date)
min_lunch(person, date)
```

Comment: I see, but if I add the column that you way in the table, i have to Create the indexes?

Comment: Fixing the datatypes is critical and should be done first. Then indexes will make things even faster. If you care about performance, you want them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very useful. Do you think that first alter the table with the things that you said, and after that create the index that you recommended? You think for example that a clustered index works or better non clustered. Sorry if i bother you but im new in this things

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't alter the table, I think you could speed up the query somewhat by using the date parts to limit the logins table to the specified date range so at least you won't be doing that cast for *every* row in the table and your indexes won't be completely useless.

```
SELECT
  loginRange.loginDt, loginRange.person
FROM
  (SELECT
    cast(logins.month || '/' || logins.day || '/' || logins.year as date) as loginDt, logins.person 
    FROM logins
    WHERE logins.month IN ('01','02','03') AND logins.year = '2010') as loginRange
  LEFT JOIN MIN_LUNCH ON
     MIN_LUNCH.person = logins.person
     AND MIN_LUNCH.date = loginRange.loginDt
```

Obviously it won't be as good as it could be if the table was using the correct data types, and if you can alter the table you should fix that instead.